# Comparing the between two data frames consisting of repetitive data and execute some operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The data under the poiid colum are unique and do not repeat itself. (dataframe name is **df1**)

[image]

On the other hand, The following dataframe can repeat poiids.

[image]

My main goal is to delete poiid in df2 if it is not found in df1. How can I handle it most effectively?

I'm adding two separate dummy dataframes for easy testing.

```
data1 = {'userid': [1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15], 
         'checkinid': [100, 120, 90, 95, 100, 130, 90, 80, 200, 120]}

data2 = {'checkinid': [100, 120, 90, 95], 
         'latitude': [-90, -92, 48, 52],
         'longitude': [42, 54, 51, -27]}
```

In these examples, some checkinids on both dataframe are different.

Expecting output according to dummy datasets for data1.

```
expectingoutput= {'userid': [1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 10, 15], 
                  'checkinid': [100, 120, 90, 95, 100,90,120]}
```

Comment: check out `isin`: df2[df2.index.isin(df1['poiid'])]`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I added dummy datasets.

Comment: Isin function generated false value even though it is the same data in other dataframe. it couldn't detect when the index place is different

Comment: Make sure the data types are the same, e.g `str` vs `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data you added. The fastest way solve it will be by merging the two dataframes, checking where you have the NaNs (which will point you to unfound keys) and then filter them out:

Here how to do it:

```
data1 = {'userid': [1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15], 
         'checkinid': [100, 120, 90, 95, 100, 130, 90, 80, 200, 120]}

data2 = {'checkinid': [100, 120, 90, 95], 
         'latitude': [-90, -92, 48, 52],
         'longitude': [42, 54, 51, -27]}

expectingoutput= {'userid': [1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 10, 15], 
                  'checkinid': [100, 120, 90, 95, 100,90,120]}

# Create df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1
```

[image]

```
# Create df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2
```

[image]

```
# Merge both dataframes using using the key checkinid 
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['checkinid'])
merged_df
```

[image]

```
# Find those rows where NaNs are present and remove them from the original DataFrame
df1[~merged_df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

[image]